# Predicate query nested fetch

Tags: jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria, lazy-initialization

I have list of predicates and use them as below.

```
criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(toArray(predicates, Predicate.class)));
```

I use the fetch for lazy as below for Person entity.

```
Root<Employment> root = criteriaQuery.from(type);
root.fetch(Employment_.person);
```

However, I need to access education entity which is mapped in Person.
I tried as below but it doesn't work.

```
root.fetch(Employment_.person, Person_.education);
```

In other words I need to do a nested fetch somehow, any suggestions?
Because at the moment if I tried to access getEmployment().getPerson().getEducation() it goes to lazy exception

Comment: Look at the stacktrace. Note that the `LazyException` will be launched by the `Person` instance (which is not a real instance but a proxy built by JPA, because you told it not to fetch `Person`). You have to fetch `Person` for this to work. And of course, if you are still in the session, no exception will happen because the proxy will resolve the values when asked..

Comment: stacktrace doesnt say much.

Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
 at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
 at com.soft.domain.Education_$$_jvst4be_b.toString(EducationLevel_$$_jvst4b